# Ruby String Interpolation Operator

Tags: ruby

I'm messing around with Ruby and I'm trying to understand how the #{} operation works.

```
b = "puts \'Hello World\'"
r = "Testing .... #{b}"
```

When running this code, nothing its printed to the screen.

However this does print to the screen

```
b = "puts \'Hello World\'"
r = "Testing .... #{puts 'Hello World'}"
```

Why does the 2nd example print to the screen and the first doesn't.

Thanks

Comment: This is like if your entire program was `"puts 'Hello World'"` vs. `puts 'Hello World'`. Sure, both programs contain `puts`, but in one of them it’s code and in the other it’s just part of a string literal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String interpolation (the `#{}` operation) evaluates everything between those braces as code and converts the returned value from execution to a string and places that string in the place of the `#{}`.

In the first example the string `r` includes `b`, and `b` is just the string `"puts \'Hello World\'"`. In this case, `"puts"` has no special meaning because it is just a string. So in this first case, `r` becomes:

```
"Testing .... #{"puts \'Hello World\'"}"
```

which then becomes:

```
"Testing .... puts \'Hello World\'"
```

In the second example you are including the final value from executing `puts 'Hello World'` within the string `r`. Since `puts` returns `nil`, `r` becomes

```
"Testing .... #{nil}"
```

which then becomes:

```
"Testing .... "
```

Comment: Ah ok this makes sense. Is there a way to get the first example to work? I guess you’d have to get it to execute first like the second. Is that possible with a variable that is a string?

Comment: @CBaker I'm not sure what your expected behavior is. If you want `r` to be the string `"Testing .... puts \'Hello World\'"`, and you want that to be printed, you can just do `puts r`. Can you explain a bit more about what you want to have happen?

Comment: @CBaker you could wrap the code in a proc: `b = -> { puts 'hello' }` and call that from within the string: `r = "Testing #{b.call}"`